# Does ARINC 429 have any error correction methods?

Tags: avionics, arinc-429

I'm currently studying the application of ARINC 429, and have noticed that ARINC 429 doesn't have an error correction but an Error detection set in the parity bit (bit-32).

Are there any means for error correction within ARINC 429? If there is, how does it solve for failed data transfer between two systems?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are no error correction methods defined a the base A429 layer. As you noticed, words with an incorrect parity bit are often simply ignored by a receiver.

At application level, additional logic usually takes place if a certain word has not been received for a sufficient amount of time. For example a flight control computer might assume that the angle of attack information is invalid if the AOA word has not been refreshed for X amount of milliseconds (either because of a parity error, or complete absence of the word on the bus).

However, there are ARINC protocols built *on top* of A429 that do have error recovery mechanisms.

For example ARINC-739 (which defines MCDU communication), defines an ACK/NAK mechanism so that the receiver system can ask the transmitting one to resend some information.

Similarly, Williamsburg protocol (also defined in A429) defines explicit ACK/NAK and retransmission in case of error.

Answer (score 2):

You wouldn't correct the ARINC 429 label, but simply ignore that transmission and wait for the label to be resent again.

If the label isn't received properly within the defined period it would be considered timed out and the last valid label would no longer be used (timed out).